# Краш при записи звука

Tags: java, android

Создаю приложение для записи звука, все по примерам, приложение крашится, думаю из за того что не получает разрешение на RECORD_AUDIO. Вот файл манифеста

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="michael.audio">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" ></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<application android:allowBackup="true"

    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".mainAct"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

А вот ошибки приложения, они как раз из за того, что приложение не запрашивает разрешение на запись звука

```
12-04 01:59:25.784 20512-20512/? E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not          create record track, status: -1
12-04 01:59:25.786 20512-20512/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
12-04 01:59:25.786 20512-20512/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
```

Comment: Дайте вопросу нормальное название отражающее проблему

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось проще и менее очевидно. Начиная шестой версии у android в коде нужно явно запрашивать разрешения, например:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD);
```